# Loading HTML page as XML

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, html-parsing

I use this to load an HTML page by XML

```
Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument()
xmlDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("index.htm"))
```

Or

```
Dim xmldoc As XDocument
xmldoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("index.htm"))
```

but I got some errors like :

- `Expecting an internal subset or the end of the DOCTYPE declaration. Line 2, position 14`;
- `'>' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '"' or '''. Line 1, position 62`;
- `Expecting an internal subset or the end of the DOCTYPE declaration. Line 5, position 20`.

All of these errors came to me when I solve one, another one shows up.

I'm asking, do I use the perfect way to load this file or is there another way for that?

Comment: 1. What language is this? 2. It's probably just malformed HTML; you'll need to run something like http://tidy.sourceforge.net/ on it first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) to parse HTML documents.

This is a .NET library that parses HTML files. The parser is very tolerant with "real world" malformed HTML. The object model is very similar to System.Xml.XmlDocument, but for HTML documents. It supports XPath and XSLT.

```
Dim htmlDoc As New HtmlDocument()
htmlDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("index.htm"))
```